# How do you use an image as background and place an image in front of that?

Tags: java, image, swing

I have tried loads of ways, but none of them succeeded. they either didn't show the image, or they made the background image disappear... do you have any suggestions? Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Main extends JFrame{

int x, y;
Image Dak;
Image Levels;
private Image dbImage;
private Graphics dbg;

public Main(){

 setTitle("Help de Pieten");
 setSize(2000, 720);
 setResizable(true);
 setVisible(true);
 setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

              try {
 this.setContentPane(
 new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new  File("Image1.gif")))));
} catch (IOException e) {}

validate(); 

ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("Image2.gif");
    Levels = i.getImage();


    x = 100;
    y = 100;
}    

public void paint(Graphics g){
        dbImage = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
    dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
    paintComponent(dbg);
    g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, this);
}


public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

 g.drawImage(Levels, x, y, this);
   repaint();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main main = new Main();

}

}
```

So how do I get images in front of the background without making the background dissapear?

Comment: Don't override `paint` for start, make sure you are calling `super.paintComponent`, but since you extended from a `JFrame`, that's not going to work anywat...

Comment: So what should I do than?

Comment: By the way, I don't care if I have to Change my whole code... I just want that image in front of my Image background. no matter how...

Comment: Delete paint method. Call in paintComponent super.paintComponent first, then draw each image in the specific order (in paintComponent) you want them (first background, then the layers above).

Comment: @TerryStorm The OP's extending from a `JFrame`, `paintComponent` won't work as `JFrame` doesn't have one ... ;)

Comment: Could you give me an example with the code I used how that would look?

Comment: @Luit Sure, check the posted answer...

Comment: It all seems so easy but it turns out to be rather complicated... ;)

Comment: oh gosh, you are right ^^ read JPanel ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with, avoid overriding the `paint` methods of top level containers like `JFrame`, they aren't double buffered and they have a complex component hierarchy with which you don't want to get involved with

Instead, start by extending from something `JPanel`, Swing components are double buffered by default, so you don't need to worry about implementing it all yourself, and overriding it's `paintComponent` method and performing your custom painting within it.

Have a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details.

Paint in Swing follows the "painters canvas" paradigm, that is, whatever is painted first, will be covered over by whatever is painted next, so to this end, make sure you paint your background first, followed by each layer in order you want it to appear.

[image: Example]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Images {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Images();
    }

    public Images() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage background;
        private BufferedImage foreground;

        public TestPane() {
            try {
                background = ImageIO.read(new File("background image"));
                foreground = ImageIO.read(new File("foreground image"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return background == null ? new Dimension(200, 200) : new Dimension(background.getWidth(), background.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            if (background != null) {
                int x = (getWidth() - background.getWidth()) / 2;
                int y = (getHeight() - background.getHeight()) / 2;
                g2d.drawImage(background, x, y, this);

            }
            if (foreground != null) {
                int x = (getWidth() - foreground.getWidth()) / 2;
                int y = (getHeight() - foreground.getHeight()) / 2;
                g2d.drawImage(foreground, x, y, this);
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Is there any difference between `Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();` and `Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;`

Comment: Yes, `g.create` actually makes a copy of the `Graphics` context, including it's state, this means you can change the copy to your hearts content, without effecting the original's state (colors, transformations, composites), everything that is "painted" to the copy will be painted to the original.  This is important, because you should return the state of the `Graphics` context to, as close to, the way it was given to you before you return from the method, as the `Graphics` context is a shared resource and may be used to paint other components on the screen

Comment: Good to know, I've always used the second approach and saved the object's state before applying transformations, so I can reset it afterwards. I thought the `create()` method is just for clipping.