# The components are showed only when I move the mouse . Help ? (Java)

Tags: java, swing

I have set the background on my Jframe with ImageIO and a repaint( drawImage).It works.
My JFrame is a JFrame form. When I add more components by dragging them on the Jframe and I run the project, the JFrame display only the first component that I added. The other components are displayed only when I moved the mouse on them. Help???

```
class Main extends JFrame { 

BufferedImage img = null;

Main() {

       try {
          img = ImageIO.read(new File("sfondo.jpg"));
       }  catch (Exception e) {

       }

       this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       initComponents(); 
       this.repaint();
       setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
       g.drawImage(img, 1, 1, null);

}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")


public static void main(String[] args) {

       Main jrframe = new Main();

}
```

Comment: pls use paintComponent instead of paint. Also call there as first thing super.paintComponent. Probably not the source of the problem, but potentially the source of other future problems

Comment: Don't override `paint` of top level containers, what do you think is painting the components?  Actually, just go have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26545536/how-do-you-use-an-image-as-background-and-place-an-image-in-front-of-that?noredirect=1#comment41714318_26545536) which demonstrates a concept for painting an image in the background.  You can set the `JPanel` as the frames content pane and just add stuff to the frame as per normal if you wanted to

Comment: @TerryStorm Again, extending from `JFrame` - no `paintComponent` method :P

Comment: and again, you are right ;)

Comment: Thank you Terry Storm. But if I use super.paintComponent() my background will not be displayed .-.

Comment: A complete example is shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2658663/230513).

Comment: A piece of code? Pls It isn't that I want to do

Answer (score 0):

@ initComponents() try to create a contentPane and add some components , e.g:

```
Container cp = getContentPane();

cp.add(component1);
```